# C# "The underlying provider failed on Open."

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, authorization

The InnerException says: "Cannot open database \"test\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'XYZ\ABC'."

So I am using visual studio 2013 and connecting to SQL 2014. The database was working before, but then I had a little bit issues with my tables, so I decided to delete the entire database, and let Entity Framework to automatically create a new one for me. When I am deleting, it does not allow me to delete without check the box says "stop all connection". I think this might be the issue.

After that, when I am trying to run the application again, this issue keeps coming back.

My SQL management Studio has the correct "XYZ\ABC" as a log-in.
[image: My SQL management Studio has the correct "XYZ\ABC" as a log-in.]

So here's my connection string in Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="test"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=true"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Any help or advice that I can try to re-establish the connection? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try it: `<add name="test" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\test;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for your response! Now my error has changed to: "Cannot attach the file 'C:\\Users\\niea\\Source\\Workspaces\\Blog\\JustBlog\\JustBlog\\App_Data\\test' as database 'test'."}.

Comment: You need to change the permissions of either folder or mdf file. some users cannot access either the folder or the mdf file as normally.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ ;).

Comment: @Kevin My problem is that I actually deleted the database, and the framework I am using is supposed be able to create a database based on the code. So I don't know if this attach database method would work or not?